# Text appearing flipped in setLabel item

Tags: pyqtgraph

I am using plotItem to plot a graph and cross hair feature to display the coordinates using mouse point. But the coordinates are appearing flipped with respect to the x-axis. I want to rotate the text by 180 deg w.r.t x-axis.
I am putting that line here.
""label.setText(" x=%0.1f  ,   y=%0.1f" % (mousePoint.x(), mousePoint.y())""
Thanks

Comment: label.setText("<span style='font-size: 6pt'> x=%0.1f <div style='text-align: center'> ,   <span style='font-size: 6pt''color: red'>y=%0.1f</span>" % (mousePoint.x(), mousePoint.y()))

Comment: I think you'll need to post some example code.